# How can i get the content of a table in a website into Microsoft Excel if the table doesn't have an ID?

Tags: html, parsing, vba, excel

I have this website that I would like to get the data in the table to Microsoft Excel.
I have used many VBA examples but couldn't get any of them to work, because the table doesn't have a name or an ID in the table tag (in the HTML).

This is the site:

http://www.tadawul.com.sa/wps/portal/!ut/p/c1/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3g_A-ewIE8TIwN3Q0tDA0_v4EDLUCNHIwMvc6B8JJK8QbCpgYGniU9YiLOPu7GBgQFJut0DwkxBuoONggO8jA08jQjo9vPIz03Vj9SPMsepyslUP0Q_0hmoKBKvooLc0IhyQ91AAJDgZts!/dl2/d1/L0lDUmlTUSEhL3dHa0FKRnNBL1lCUlp3QSEhL2Vu/?symbol=4003&tabOrder=2&chart_type=chart_oneDay&announcmentNumber=&isAnnual=

How can I do 'grab' the table data and put it into Excel?

[Editor's note 13 Nov: verified the URL to be legit.]

Comment: A table typically has a specific positioning in the document, even if it has no Id or name. So you can do something like `Set tbl = document.getElementsByTagName("table")(3)` to get a reference to the third table on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The table you are hunting for is on the 21st (!!!) level below the document root (`<html>`) and has a **class** attribute set to the value of "**Table3**"

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="Table3">
```

which is used only once throughout the whole HTML and hence gives a rather good selection criterium. So I suggest you do something like

```
Dim Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ECol As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim IFld As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set ECol = Doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
    For Each IFld In ECol
        If VarType(IFld.getAttribute("class")) <> vbNull Then
            If IFld.getAttribute("class") = "Table3" Then

                ' further process the Inner HTML of IFld ...

            End If
        End If
    Next
' ...
```

Checking for the VarType first before checking the String value is to detect & exclude table elements which don't contain any class element in which case the `If` on class name would fail with an error.

VBA debugger and the <kbd>F8</kbd> key are your friends!

Comment: MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection  ---->compile error : userdefined type not defined

Comment: I guess you created a reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library" (...\mshtml.tlb - containing the def of the Collection) and "Microsoft Internet Controls" (...\ieframe.dll) ?